# Sequential model recommendation for text classification without deep learning?

Tags: natural-language

I am doing a NLP project, I have about 500 lines of data and my goal is to have a binary classification model, if 1, then the input text is talking about a subject and if 0, the input text is not talking about this subject.

Because of the small amount of data and the fact that I am new to NLP, I am using traditional machine learning with bag of words, but my result is not good enough and getting more data is impossible. Actually it is easy to get text that is not related to the subject, but text related to the subject I cannot find anymore.

I was then wandering about using models that could use the sequence of words as input, so the model would not only know the words used, but in which order they appear.After some research I could only find models based on deep learning that could use the word sequence. But, as far as I know, deep learn need more data than I have. So I wanted to ask if is there a way to use traditional machine learning and use word sequence as a feature to learn? And which ones are good against a small text dataset? Also, my goal here is to learn, so if there are some good articles related to my issue that you guys think are relevant, please share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, because it's based on deep learning, but you may want to consider doing transfer learning to fine-tune a pre-built [transformer model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762).  Transformer models for NLP are considered to be very good.  Yes, you may not have enough data to get great results, but you don't know until you try.